# New Server and New IIS

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, iis, iis-7, iis-6

We have an older Windows Server 2003 server:

[image: Win2003]

It is running a couple of our internal websites in IIS:

[image: Win2003IIS]

Work requires I block out anything that identifies them.

Windows Server 2003 is entering its End Of LiveCycle, so work has purchased a new computer and installed Windows Server 2008 on it:

[image: Win2008wIIS]

As illustrated in the screenshot, it is also loaded with IIS 6.0, but there is nothing in it.

I am a software developer that typically works in Visual Studio. All of the other developers here work with NetBeans to make PHP or Java applications. Since I know more about Windows than the other developers, I have been assigned the role of migrating our existing websites over to this new server.

I'm looking on Microsoft about how to get started with it, and I notice they show IIS 7, IIS 8, and IIS 8.5:

[Microsoft IIS • Getting Started with IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/getting-started-with-iis)

[image: MSIIS]

Now I see that I'd need to specifically look up migrating data for an older server, but I don't know how long the older IIS is going to be supported.

- Is IIS 6 that outdated?
- Can I update our company Win2008 server to a newer IIS free of charge?
- What version of IIS should I get?
- Where can I find out how to start migrating our existing servers over with little or no downtime?

My deadline for getting this done has been set to December 2014, so I have a little time to figure this out, but not enough time to get certified in it.

Comment: No problem. Hopefully, someone can help you with your issue, but unfortunately, I can't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is IIS 6 that outdated?

Yes, it's about a decade old now.  Is it *too* outdated? Depends on what you're using it for. There's no advantage to staying with IIS6 if a newer version are available for your OS.

> Can I update our company Win2008 server to a newer IIS free of charge?

Yes, you can download and install IIS7.5 on Server 2008 R2.  Check with Microsoft: [Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/cc771209.aspx)

> What version of IIS should I get?

The latest version that your OS supports.  For Server 2008 R2, that'd be v7.5.

[Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Information_Services#History)

> Where can I find out how to start migrating our existing servers over with little or no downtime?

That's impossible for us (or anyone) to answer this for you, as we have no idea what resources your websites depend on.  And depending on the resources and methods used in creation (which we are unaware of) I'm not convinced we could point you in a direction that's at all specific.

If its a simple web page with relative paths just create a new site and copy the contents over. If it's a simple web app, create a new site, assign an Application Pool and copy things over.

If the projects were fully developed in Visual Studio, then it may be easiest to just re-publish from VS directly into IIS.

Basically, start migrating in your chosen way (depending on your needs) and work out problems one at a time.

If/when you get stuck migrating, come back to the Stack Exchange sites (could be here, might be better on ServerFault, or WebDevelopers - depending on the problem) with specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: +1. So far, I'm looking at that link on installing IIS. It says to use the **Add Roles** wizard, then talks about using the Web PI. I'm not sure what role to add.

Comment: The one I would naturally assume, **Web Server (IIS)** is already checked and grayed out because it is already installed.

Comment: OK, I see it. It's further down the page. This should get me all fixed up (I hope).

Comment: One thing I didn't mention is that you _DO NOT_ have II6 on Server 2008, you are just using the IIS6 _management tools_ instead of the newer ones.  Both are provided with Windows 2008 for compatibility reasons, as you can't manage an IIS6 server from the IIS7+ management tools (if memory serves me correctly :) ).

Comment: I now have a fresh instance of IIS running. Would you know of a good spot to go to see how to configure 2 or more folders to serve as separate websites, and how to setup the Application Pools? I did those one time a little over a year ago, but someone worked with me here at that time and walked me through it. I didn't take notes. :(